# Soundproofing a room cost effectively

Tags: windows

I am looking to get the most bang for my buck when attempting to limit the noise coming in to our bedroom from the neighbours house. The cost of re-plastering the wall is out of the question.

I have searched around the internet and found that perhaps the large majority of the noise will be coming through the window we have facing the neighbours house in the room. This seems to be where we will get the most noise reduction for the cost of implementing it.  It is approx 1m x 1.5m in size.

Would the best solution to this problem be to get this window double glazed? There are a number of technologies for noise reduction and windows, what are some experiences others have had?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before you replace the windows, you may want to try sound dampening drapes. Google search and a few companies will offer solutions for home theaters and other rooms.

I have single pane windows in my house. In the winter I install a second, plexiglass insert to help with heating costs. But it does make a huge difference with noise. If you want to experiment, get some scrap plastic or plywood and cover your window. It will look terrible but at least you'll get a feel for how it would be.

Comment: Unfinished sentence at end?

Comment: Interesting ideas, thanks very much Micahel.  I especially like the idea of the sound dampening drapes and boarding up the window temporarily to test whether the window is actually the problem.